# FontAwsome font awesome not working in internet explorer 8/9/10 amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, font-awesome

It seems like FontAwesome is not working on Amazon S3. I'm getting below error for Internet Explorer

```
 @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted.
```

I do have CORS configured below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

This now seems to be working with Firefox (it had the same error on it before the CORS config) but still not on IE.

I thought it was caching issue but this was done 2 days ago.

Is there any other config that I need to do to fix this error and display icons on IE aswell?

Comment: @Bubbles where would you put this under CORS config?

Comment: Sorry, that comment was my bad - I think I was confusing names. I think what I linked was the equivalent of the `AllowedOrigin` rule.

Comment: have you tried clearing your IE cache?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `AllowedOrigin` to `http://*.yourdomain.com`?

Oh, and you didn't say you were using CloudFront, but if you are, S3+CloudFront have some major issues with CORS support when you try to use them together.

Comment: Hi, I'm not using Cloudfront. Just S3 but I've just put my domain name on it and saved. So I'd say wait a little while until cache is refreshed...